# Directive to directive communication using a service

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to perform the following. Use one directive to set information in a service.
Use another directive to retrieve information from this service. The directive setting the information seems to be doing it's job fine, however the one receiving the information does not react to it.

Below are how the directives look:

```
app.service('theStore',function(){
  this.data;
});

app.directive('theOneThatSets', ['theStore', function(theStore){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.click(function(event){
        theStore.data = attrs.val;
      });
    }
  };

}]);

app.directive('theOneThatReads', ['theStore', function(theStore){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<stong>Received Text is - {{receivedValue}}</strong>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('theStore.data',function(newVal){
        scope.receivedValue = theStore.data;
      });
    }
  };

}]);
```

plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9EMIwhUcneQoopNqqWtV

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do watchers on things that are not in scope. The best way to communicate between controllers/services/directives is to use $rootScope, $broadcast, and $on.

Example using your code:

```
    app.directive('theOneThatSets', ['$rootScope', function(theStore){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.click(function(event){
            //theStore.data = attrs.val;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('changeThisValue', attrs.val); // Send
          });
        }
      };

    }]);

    app.directive('theOneThatReads', [function(theStore){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<stong>Received Text is - {{receivedValue}}</strong>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$on('changeThisValue', function($event, value){
              scope.receivedValue = theStore.data;
          });
        }
      };
    }]);
```

also, try creating a listener in your service like so:

```
    app.service('myservice',function(){
        this.listen = function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch(function(){return someScopeValue},function(){
               //$scope.dosomestuff();
            });
        }
    });

    //your controller

    function myCtrl($scope,myservice) {
        $scope.listen = function() {
            myservice.listen($scope);
        }

        //call your method
        $scope.listen();
    }
```

Comment: I am already using the broadcast .. on mechanism and that seems to be working slow and hence I was looking for alternatives

Comment: how slow are we talking here? The broadcast/on mechanism is pretty instant. I constantly use it in my code with no issues.

Comment: Be careful : using `$rootScope` is a bad practice, it's better to avoid using it.